# Automatic image scroll (smooth) with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to create my own jQuery animation for my wordpress site, because there is no wordpress plugin for my need and I do not want to use a jquery plugin, it creates issues inside wordpress.

My html consist of a list of horizontal images, that I just want scroll smoothly to the left, automatically (almost like a website ad display that scrolls automatically)

How would I do this?

I tried the following, but the scrolling is not smooth....

Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tUj3N/15/)

Code:

jQuery:

```
var w = $('#clientsSlider ul').width();

$('#clientsSlider > ul').animate({
     left: -w
  }, 30000)
```

HTML:

```
<div id="clientsSlider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="..." /></li>
        <li><img src="..." /></li>
        <li><img src="..." /></li>
        <li><img src="..." /></li>
        <li><img src="..." /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it by

- merging your images into 1 .png file
- Set image ans element background, repeated (0 center)
- Animate with jQuery the background-position

```js
(function slide(){
  $('#clientsSlider').animate({backgroundPosition : '-=2px'}, 20, 'linear', slide);
})();
```

```css
#clientsSlider{
  height: 96px;
  background: #e5e5e5 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kejzw.png) repeat 0 center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clientsSlider"></div>
```

Merge your images into a single one:

[image: TM LOGOS]
<sup>(©disclaimer: The randomly picked logos used for the purpose of this Answer and related Demo Example - are trademarks and in property of their respective owners.)</sup>

---

### If you want to add a *click* functionality to every logo

yes, on a background image, and *pause on hover* do like:

```js
var $sl = $('#clientsSlider'),
    slPos = 0,
    goTo = "",
    totW = 1254, // total image width
    imgMap = {
      /* logoEndsAtPX  : "urlToFollow" */
      366  : "planet.html",
      516  : "absa.html",
      766  : "kumbra.html",
      1051 : "bosch.html",
      1254 : "samancor.html"
    };

function slide(){
  slPos -= 1 ;
  $sl.animate({backgroundPosition : slPos}, 10, 'linear', slide);
}

$sl.hover(function(ev) {
  return ev.type=='mouseenter' ? $(this).stop() : slide() ;
}).on('click', function( ev ) {
  var mX = ev.clientX - $(this).offset().left;
  var mFixed = (Math.abs(slPos) + mX)  % totW;
  console.log(mFixed);
  $.each(imgMap, function( key, val ){
    goTo = val;
    if(key>mFixed)return false;
  }); 
  alert( goTo ); // DO WITH URL WHATEVER YOU LIKE
});

slide(); // START!
```

```css
#clientsSlider{
  height: 96px;
  background: #e5e5e5 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kejzw.png) repeat 0 center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clientsSlider"></div>
```

Comment: thank you very much roXon - How would I pause the animation on mouseHover?

Comment: also, it is a good idea, but what if I would like users to be able to click on each of the the images?

Comment: @DextrousDave Pause on hover: http://jsbin.com/olikom/7/edit - No, you cannot click.

Comment: could you please look at the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MNT4e/68/ - Why is the next image (from the far right) taking so long to show? It is not showing instantly...Also, whe I implemented this in my wordpress site, only the first 3 images show, stops and reloads the same 3 images in the animation again...what could the issue be?

Comment: @DextrousDave you're doing it the wrong way. The images have not enough space to show and they're jumping all over the place (inside the parent element) I'll show you soon another way to do it.

Comment: thanks man...BTW, is it possible to add scroll options to your animation - thats is, the ability to scroll back and forth between the images?

Comment: @DextrousDave it would be much more programming. Any way edited my demo to add the CLICK - follow logo url.

Comment: This is some great work. thank you. Any way to control the scrolling?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `duration` is far to high. Thats why it can't be smooth.
Your animation now takes `30 seconds` (30000 miliseconds) to be finished.

There are not enough pixels inside the range of your animation to look smooth with a that long duration.

Comment: thank you, but if you play with my fiddle you will see that if I set it to say 6000 it scrolls way to fast, so I adjusted it to my required speed...

Answer (score 1):

Here are some cool plugins and examples of Horizontal auto-scrollers - Called **Marquees**

http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FWWEn/) example

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrW5q/) example with pause on mouseover:

Some code to quiet the damn stackoverflow "links to JSfiddle must be accompanied by ...blabla"

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.textWidth = function(){
             var calc = '<span style="display:none">' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
             $('body').append(calc);
             var width = $('body').find('span:last').width();
             $('body').find('span:last').remove();
            return width;
        };....see the fiddle
```